# Houston:admin Iron router onBeforeAction except

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Newbie trying to use houston:admin in Meteor project with iron-router

In iron-router's hook onBeforeAction, with except: [ ... ], like

`Router.onBeforeAction({
    if (!Meteor.user()) {
        Router.go('\login');
    }
}, {except: ['login']});`

What should I put inside except:[] to make houston:admin an exception?
Or if there exists a better way.

Thanks very much for helping!

Comment: You don't want to do a `Route.go()` in `onBeforeAction`. You want`if ( Meteor.userId() ){ this.next(); } else { this.render('login') };`

Comment: Yes, thanks very much, but the code above is just a sample. And I don't think .go or .render has anything to do with my question.

Comment: It doesn't, but it might help you with your *next* question! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't future proof, i.e. if any additional pages are added to the houston project this would fail on those but for just now you can use:

`{except: ['houston_home', 'houston_collection', 'houston_document', 'houston_change_password', 'houston_custom_template', 'houston_login']}`

to keep an eye on the routes you need to add and put any news ones in they would be anything in the list here (or here abouts if the file changes) https://github.com/gterrono/houston/blob/master/client/router.coffee#L100 but with `houston_` at the beginning. The line you are looking for looks like this:

`BASE_HOUSTON_ROUTES = (Houston._houstonize_route(name) for name in ['home', 'collection', 'document', 'change_password', 'custom_template'])`

Comment: no problem, as Michel Floyd says though you will need to put a this.next() in there to avoid issues with IR and nasty looking console outputs :D